# Update table with WCF-SQL adapter

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have created an Orchestration where I am trying to fetch all the rows from the `Request` table with `Created` status. I want to update these rows with `Completed` status.

I wrote a SP to fetch all the rows with `Created` status and I am able to get these values in my orchestration (I tried sending these values to a flat file and I am able see the values in output file.)

I wrote another SP to update the status to `Completed` by passing the `RequestID`. I added Transform control to my orchestration to map `RequestID` received from select SP to `RequestID`parameter in update SP. I compiled and deployed this project, but at runtime I am getting the following error:

> There was a failure executing the send pipeline:
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML assembler" Send Port:
>   "LogPort" URI: "C:\Data\Log\%MessageID%.xml" Reason: Root element is
>   missing.

I guess I doing something wrong in the mapping. But I'm not sure how to do it in the right way. I am using BizTalk 2010, VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008. I would like to know how to do the following:

1. How to debug BizTalk project.
2. How to map results for select query with update procedure.

Comment: I fixed this issue which was causing the error. I made a mistake in one of the message assignment control. I was calling a wrong method instead of calling the method which will return the message for update SP. I am able to send the generated message to a output file and see the constructed message. But I still need to know how to loop thru the results of select query and call the update procedure for each row returned in select query.